# Why is spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown by default false in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, orc

Why is `spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown` default value false in spark?

Does setting `spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown` value to `true` incur some performance overhead or there is some limitation in spark's orc read functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because spark integration with old format of orc was not very good, and would cause issues in some cases. Most of these problems seem to be fixed in new format of ORC (has better vectorization) and spark 2.

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/148917/orc-improvements-for-apache-spark-22.html
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14962
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/222760/spark-sql-limit-clause-performance-issues.html